# Avoiding Memory Issues with SQL Alchemy and pandas read_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, memory, singlestore

I have a query that obtains all records in a day for certain conditions, and this query is inserted into a python loop to obtain data from my MySQL (memsql I believe) database.

I am receiving the following error (masked some info) at some point throughout my loops depending on query output size:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1712, 'Leaf Error (ip_address:port): Query execution memory use (xxx MB) has reached the maximum memory for its resource pool `pool_name` (y%).')
```

The relevant bits of code for the query is setup as follows:

```
engine = create_engine(engine_string, echo=False)
for day in year:
    query = "sql query with variables that change the days within the loop"
    df = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
```

What I find most odd here is that if I change the query to be more restrictive and reduce the resultant dataset, I can iterate through more days of queries before the memory error is envoked.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: My guess is that memory used to store query results within the database isn't freed as you loop. I expect there shall be some way to tell the database that you don't need query result any more. BTW what is pd in your example? What is the number of rows in each query result?

Comment: @ivan_onys - Ahh interesting, I didn't think the database would hold the loop information after the send of data. I'll look into that... pd is my alias for pandas import in python, python is executing the queries after creating the connection engine string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show status extended;` command to check the assigned and utilized resources then you can make changes accordingly to SingleStore's configurations.

You can go thru the following [documentation](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/reference/troubleshooting-reference/identifying-and-reducing-memory-usage.html) for more info.